# arg of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPSTR" c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

Hey guys I'm sorry to ask this but I haven't found my answer online. So i keep getting the error "arg of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPSTR"" when compiling one of my projects. How ever when i send it to my friend same code same everything he can compile it were both on windows 10 using visual studio 2017. Here is the Source code

```
    void RunProcess()
{
    runSetDebugPrivs();
    while (!FindProcessName("csgo.exe", &__gameProcess)) Sleep(12);
    while (!(getThreadByProcess(__gameProcess.th32ProcessID))) Sleep(12);
    __HandleProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);
    while (__dwordClient == 0x0) __dwordClient = GetModuleNamePointer("client.dll", __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);
    while (__dwordEngine == 0x0) __dwordEngine = GetModuleNamePointer("engine.dll", __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);
    while (__dwordVGui == 0x0) __dwordVGui = GetModuleNamePointer("vguimatsurface.dll", __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);
    __HWNDCss = FindWindow(NULL, "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive");
}
```

};

Comment: I'd wager you are using MSVC 15.5 or later, while your friend does not.

Comment: The errors are on lines 
while (__dwordClient == 0x0) __dwordClient = GetModuleNamePointer("client.dll", __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);
    while (__dwordEngine == 0x0) __dwordEngine = GetModuleNamePointer("engine.dll", __gameProcess.th32ProcessID);
    while (__dwordVGui == 0x0) __dwordVGui = GetModuleNamePointer("vguimatsurface.dll", __gameProcess.th32ProcessID); so 7 8 and 9

Comment: Go to your project options, find the "Conformance Mode" option under C/C++\Language and change it to "No". If you are serious about learning C++, you should get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and make sure that option is "Yes" on your future projects.

Comment: Thank you so much and i have a few ebooks im working out of

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the first parameter of `GetModuleNamePointer` function wants non-const `char*` string, but you put there `const char*` literal when you call the function. Literal constants are always `const char*`. The cause of this is probably the fact that other flavour of C language doesn't differentiate these in this condition. One possible fix is to change declaration of that function to accept `LPCSTR` (a.k.a. `const char*`) in the first parameter instead of `LPSTR` (a.k.a. `char*`).

You didn't show `GetModuleNamePointer` function, so I can only guess. If it is what I found on hack forums, it is declared like this:

```
DWORD GetModuleNamePointer(LPSTR LPSTRModuleName, DWORD __DwordProcessId);
```

But it can work with const safely, so you can simply change it to

```
DWORD GetModuleNamePointer(LPCSTR LPSTRModuleName, DWORD __DwordProcessId);
```

After this change in declaration it will be compatible with your compiler.

As already pointed out by @StoryTeller in comments, you can also disable the standard conformance in compiler. Here is description what it does and why it helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance

In short: Correct behavior is, maybe surprisingly, when your LPSTR program does't work. It works on older compilers, while new ones follow the standards more strictly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from [this forum entry](https://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1330000). Go to Project "Properties -> C\C++ -> Language" and make sure the "Conformance mode" is set to "NO"